# Best practice on implementing a load more in meteor

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, meteor

I would like to have a list with 10 items, at the bottom of the list there should be a load more button. When clicked it adds another ten items to the list.

I already came up with a session that keeps track of the limit property.. But the problem is that meteor then reloads the full list instead of just adding another 10..

I would be very thankful for an elegant solution.

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smart package provides an easy way to do pagination:

https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-paginated-subscription

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, the most complete solution for paging in Meteor looks to be **meteor-pages**:

https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages

It provides UI components and iron router integration as well. If you are only looking for infinite scroll without page navigation the simpler **meteor-paginated-subscription** might suit you well enough though:

https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-paginated-subscription

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at preserve? That should do it.

http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve